# Dynamic fluid (interacting with gravity in real-time) on complex mesh surface

Tags: textures, shader, mesh

My question put simply is this:
In detail how is the blood that goes along the characters surface done?
It is shown in this video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Xrmgsz76Yc) from 0:34 and onwards.

Ok so now some more details about what I have looked into (I have been trying to achieve this affect for a couple of weeks now with no success):
I have tried a kind of brute force method where I get the triangles (character mesh triangles) that are intersected by a plane and calculate the line equations for each triangle in order to draw a line (for the slash). For dripping down a surface however I tried creating a triangle map that held indexes to the triangles that were attached to each triangle by their edges. Then I did line that went along the surface of each triangle in the direction of gravity. This takes a lot of processor power and generally gives a bad effect. When trying to increase the thickness of drips it creates lots of additional problems and thus doesn't work at all.

I looked into octree textures and their uses in simulating liquid flowing across a surface, however I am not sure how to implement this and this as far as I can see will not work with gravity.

I am currently looking into Cg shaders and thinking this is where the solution lies. I found another video by the same team (Wolfire) implying the use of a shader for the blood effects shown [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1IsxDQ5cPg). I have looked for shader examples that might give me a clue into how it is done but I have had no luck so far.

I'm using the language C# and Cg for shaders. If anyone feels like giving any code to help with explanations etc then any language will do and I'll have a go at converting :-)

Thank you to whoever helps me because like I said earlier in this post I've spent a fair bit of time trying to work this out and my brain is starting to hurt.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a shader trick/s than dynamic fluid such as Smoothed Particle Hydrodynamics.

Firstly, the videos above were created by a really good graphics programmer (IMO).  Just be aware that getting the same or a similar effect won't be an easy task.

He states that he stores a unique "blood texture" which store the amount of blood at each texel.

When adding an injury you would increment the blood amount at the wound location(to the blood map).

Each frame update the blood map given a few criteria:

- For each texel -> If there is much blood in the texels above... increase blood amount at the current texel.
- You would need to identify what is "above" by checking world coordinates within the shader
- If you want to match the video, you would also have to check for vertical gaps. Dripping.
- Decrease overall blood amount at all texels to a certain min (to allow the system to slow down over time)

What happens when dripping blood hits a "horizontal surface"?  It looks like he adds a decal to the horizontal surface, which is increased at each "drip".

Good luck

Edit: 
Here's a crappy(1 hour dev time) example of sliding blood I just made... it's in GLSL... you'll need a decent graphics card and a webGL compliant browser to view it.
  http://glsl.heroku.com/e#6237.48

Comment: Thank you for your response and the example you've given has helped enlighten me on the subject. However my mind gets a little confused when thinking about how this could be applied to a mesh that isn't a plane. With a plane a texel that is below another texel will most likely correspond to two positions on the plane where one part is actually below another part. It gets complicated when you have uv mapping on a complex mesh such as the bunny's or indeed majority of characters. The different uv coords mean that a texel below another texel could be in an entirely different place on the mesh :-/

Comment: Also do you think there is any chance of decals being used? I know that when the blood hits the floor a decal is almost definitely what is being used but I'm talking about on the body, perhaps decals are being dynamically placed along the surface of the bunny's?

Comment: Regarding your second point about decals being used.... no, there is a whole other set of textures which are drawn to that represent blood.  So if you have six different textures on 6 faces of a cube (checkerboard, diagonal lines, etc), then you would need another 6 (empty) textures to represent blood.  A shader would then mix the 2 textures on output.

Comment: And regarding the 1st point.  Yeah that is a challenge.  For each texel, you would likely need 3 pieces of information:
1) A texture space to world space matrix (so you know which way is up)
2) This texels world pos
3) This texels normal.y in world space, so you can determine speed of blood flow.

I'm just guessing here though.  Like I said, it's a very nice blood effect, done by a pro.

Finally you could ask the question of the developers... maybe here: http://www.reddit.com/r/overgrowth

Answer (score 0):

This is way too late, but I'll leave it here for future generations. The Wolfire blood splatter effect seems to be a (very) upgraded version of a nVidia Gravity Maps sample. The sample can be found here:

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/samples.html#HLSL_BloodShader

and there are also slides from a GDC presentation here:

ftp://download.nvidia.com/developer/presentations/GDC_2004/gdc2004_BloodShader.pdf